# Text based java spreadsheet cells

Tags: java

I'm working on a text based spreadsheet project for my java class. I have the actual spread sheet printing out and i have cell inputs in the form of an array. The problem is getting the cell inputs to appear in the spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet prints through a loop and looks similar to this:

```
    | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
  --|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   1|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  --|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   2|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  --|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   3|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  --|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   4|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  --|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   5|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  --|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
```

Any ideas on how i could get my inputs from the array to print in the spreadsheet? I'm not really looking for a straight solution to my problem, just a push in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

The spreadsheet is made through System.out.print();

P.S. I would have posted a screen cap of the spreadsheet but my account is low level. Sorry for the low quality.

edit: I cant post the exact code to print the spreadsheet right now (Saved on a different computer) but i can offer a description. Basically i'm printing each row of the spreadsheet grid within a for loop. The letters are a char variable that changes in the loop. Same goes for the numbers except they are int variables. The entire thing is just being printed with characters in the console.

edit: Here is the code that prints the spreadsheet:

```
for (char x = 'A' ; x <= 'G' ; x++) {
    System.out.print("      " + x + "       |");
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("---+--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+");
System.out.println("");
if (i == 0) {
    // 10-99 digit loop
    for (int j = 1 ; j <= length ; j++) {
        if (j >= 10) {
                System.out.print("" + j + " |              |              |              |              |              |              |              |");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("---+--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else {
            // 1-9 digit loop
            System.out.print(" " + j + " |              |              |              |              |              |              |              |");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("---+--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+" + "--------------+");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Its not very well optimized yet(I will deal with that once i get everything working) but it does print the spreadsheet right.

Comment: *"would have posted a screen cap of the spreadsheet but my account is low level. Sorry for the low quality."*  Thank goodness for that.  Code is more useful than a screen-shot here.  What is yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post a complete example, so I'm going have to make some assumptions.

I'll assume that your array in question is a 2D array. So the cell A1 refers to `[0][0]` in the array.

In order to make your columns the correct widths, you're going to want to scan your array and determine the largest string (because I'm assuming your array contains strings). That's the width of the column. If you don't figure this out, you'll just get a mess of formatting.

Perhaps a better alternative would be to use tabs and not use these lines at all?

At any rate, that means the number of `-`s printed out will be dynamic. You should use a utility method for that. Something that takes in the column name, loops through all the elements in that column of the array (determining the width of the column), and finally returning that many `-`s (as a string). Note any spacing in the table will have to be taken into account.

Now with the table's outline properly sized, we can loop through the 2D array, printing out the `|`s and the elements.

Here's a very basic example that doesn't calculate the size of the columns:

```
    String [][] tableData = { {"abc", "def"}, {"ghi", "jkl"} };

    // The header
    System.out.println("+-----+-----+-----+");
    System.out.println("|     |  A  |  B  |");
    System.out.println("+-----+-----+-----+");

    int rowNumber = 1;
    // The body
    for(String[] row : tableData)
    {
        // Numbers
        System.out.print("|  " + rowNumber + "  ");

        // Elements
        for(String element : row)
        {
            System.out.print("| " + element + " ");
        }

        // New line for the end of the row
        System.out.println("|");
        rowNumber++;
    }

    // Footer
    System.out.println("+-----+-----+-----+");
```

In this case, we didn't have to calculate how much spacing and `-`s we need because we already know the size of the data (exactly 3 characters wide). This prints out:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | abc | def |
|  2  | ghi | jkl |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, you gave me some great information. I think i have an idea of how i can make this work. Also, i'm sorry for my post being unclear (This was my first one).

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert your column letter into an integer index so you can use it as the index into your two-dimensional array. Might also need to subtract 1 from your row index to get the other index into the two-dimensional array.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention it, but i do convert the letters into integers. Basically i want to know how to "update" the printed spreadsheet with the inputs i enter. for example if i enter A3 = 100 i need to have 100 appear in the spreadsheet.

Comment: That's not what your question says! I'm not going to answer your question in case you change it again!

Comment: That is what the question says "Any ideas on how i could get my inputs from the array to print in the spreadsheet?"

Comment: Your posted code DOESN'T actually convert letters into integers. You might want to reconsider the usefulness of my answer.